# KiCad EeSchema search for net by name

Tags: pcb, schematics, hardware, kicad

Is there a way to search for a net by name in KiCad EeSchema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way in KiCad version 6 is to have both PCB Editor and Schematic Editor open at the same time.  In the PCB Editor, use the menu option "Inspect->Net Inspector"

[image: KiCad Net Inspector]

There, you can find the net you are interested in.  It will be shown on the board.

From there, you need to close the window and highlight the net using either `Ctrl-Click` or the `~` hotkey.  This will cause the associated net to be highlighted in your Schematic Editor as well

[image: Crossprobe highlights]